# OpenGL Anistroping filtering not working as expected

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to detect and if supported - enable GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT in my OpenGL ES 1.1 game. The device reports that the extension is supported, returns me the proper maximum anistropic level, but when I try to enable it I get GL_INVALID_ENUM.

Here is the code that I use now:

```
if(GLES11.glGetString(GLES11.GL_EXTENSIONS).contains("GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic"))
{
    System.out.println("will use GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic");
    GLES11.glGetError();//clean any prevous errors
    GLES11.glTexParameteri(GLES11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, GetMaxAnisotropy());
    int err = GLES11.glGetError();
    System.out.println("error : "+err);//<- prints 1280 (GL_INVALID_ENUM)
}
```

and here is how I get the maximum supported level

```
private int GetMaxAnisotropy()
{
    int[] maxAnisotropy = new int[1];

    GLES11.glGetIntegerv(GLES11Ext.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, maxAnisotropy, 0);
    System.out.println("max: "+maxAnisotropy[0]);//<-- prints 16
    return maxAnisotropy[0];
}
```

Any ideas what may be the cause of this problem?

Here is the output from the logcat:

```
05-21 13:42:03.070: I/System.out(14110): error : 1280
05-21 13:42:03.070: I/System.out(14110): will use GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
05-21 13:42:03.070: I/System.out(14110): maxAnisotropy: 16.0
05-21 13:42:03.070: E/Adreno-ES11(14110): <qglDrvAPI_glTexParameterfv:75>: GL_INVALID_ENUM
```

Comment: According to https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt, the anisotropy value is a float. Have you tried setting it using `TexParameterf`?

Comment: Yes, both float and int calls give the same result.

Comment: I assume that you actually have a 2D texture bound when you make that call? Anisotropy is per-texture object in ES... in desktop GL you can set it per-sampler object.

Comment: Yes, the texture is bound, if I comment this call everything works as intended.